# declare point arry size int main function c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Kmean{
public:
    class Point{
        public:
        double Xcoord;
        double Ycoord;
        int Lable;
        double Distance;
    };
        int k;
        int numPts;
        Point** pointSet;
        int numRows;
        int numCols;
        int** displayAry;
        Point** KcentroidAry;
        int change;

};
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    Kmean km;
    ifstream inFile(argv[1]);
    km.k=atoi(argv[2]);
    ofstream outFile1(argv[3]);
    ofstream outFile2(argv[4]);
    inFile>>km.numRows;
    inFile>>km.numCols;
    km.displayAry=new int*[km.numRows][km.numCols];

    //  inFile>>km.numPts;
//  km.pointSet[km.numPts];
//  km.KcentroidAry[km.k+1];
//  km.loadPointSet(inFile,km.pointSet);
//  km.kMeanClustering(km.pointSet, km.k, km.KcentroidAry);
    inFile.close();
    outFile1.close();
    outFile2.close();

}
```

here is my code, I was trying to declare the km.displayAry and km.point and km.KcentroidAry size, but it says
 'km' cannot appear in a constant-expression, i dont know how to fix it ,the size is read from the input file

Comment: is there any reason for not using `std::vector` ?

Comment: my professor ask me to `displayAry (** int)` and Dynamically allocate a 2-D arrays, size numRows by numCols in main funciton

Comment: `new int*[km.numRows][km.numCols];` is wrong. Hope the duplicate helps

Comment: yeah, i know this part is wrong, but I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: did you read the duplicate question and its answers? The link is on the top

Comment: yeah, I just down the reading on the top, it helps me a lot, and I fix my error, I just remembered I saw this before, and I kind of did same error but I fixed it last time, but the memory just wipe out, thank you so much